# How to configue web.xml for apache tomcat 8.0.5

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I have apache tomcat 8.0.5 installed on my machine. I have written a servlet called Test.java and saved the class file Test.class it in the directory : "apache-tomcat 8.0.5/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes"
But when I tried to run it through browser, it gave error message as: "The requesetd resource not available". How should I modify the web.xml file to run the servlet?

Comment: This is not really a Tomcat issue, but on servlet development.  Look for a tutorial or book on basic Servlet development.  That should answer your questions.  As @Stefoan pointed out, there are lots of them available on Google.

Comment: @Daniel, Yes, I already looked it up and I figured out the answer
Thank You very much for your efforts though :)